# Differentiation map

Tags: linear-algebra

When we study linear homomorphism. We have an example of surjective of a linear homomorphism as follows:

$V:=K[x]$, $K$ is an arbitary field and the linear map $\bf{T}$ as follows

$\begin{aligned} \bf{T} : V  & \rightarrow \bf{V} \\ a_{0}+a_{1}x+a_{2}x^{2}+\ldots+a_{n}x^{n} & \rightarrow a_{1}+2a_{2}x+...+na_{n}x^{n-1} \end{aligned}$

So in order to prove this map is surjective, we need to prove for every $p(x) \in V$, there exists $q(x)$ such that $T(q)=p$. But when I try to do this, I observe that this leads to prove that for a given $b \in K$ and $n \in N$ prove that there is $c\in K$ such that $nc=b$. How to prove this property in arbitary field $K$ ?

Comment: I am not convinced that this is true if char(K) $\neq 0$. If char(K) = p, what is an antiderivative of $x^{p-1}$?

Comment: I also think about it. Because, when I read some example on the internet, it write arbitary field, but I only prove the case $K$ which is real numbers, but don't know how to do that in arbitary field K :(.

Comment: You can do it for other fields than $\mathbb{R}$. If $char(K) = 0$, then $K$ contains a field isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$, so the antiderivative of $x^n$ is $\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$ and there is no problem with the division.

Answer (score 2):

If $char(K) = 0$, then you can just write down an antiderivative and call it a day.

But if $char(K) = p$, I am not convinced this is true.

If we say want to find an antiderivative of $x^{p-1}$, well from calculus we know that it should be $\frac{x^p}{p}$. But in $K$, $p=0$.